# Finder Synch Extension Waiting to Attach in XCode 7.0.1 OSX 10.10

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I have written a Finder Synch extension with Swift and add to my project target in XCode 7.0.1. At first run, it works as normal but after several runs, it stall on Extension Waiting to Attach. If I open a Finder window, nothing happened and my class init never called.

Do you face any problem like this? Using Mac OSX 10.10.5 Yosemite with XCode 7.0.1.

Comment: It is interesting that if I change the extension bundle identifier, it works again and then again not working. If change again,same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also, make sure your entitlements and certificates / signing are set correctly. Working with a non signed finder sync extension caused exactly the problems you described.

edit: one more thing, the optional relaunch (alt + right click on finder) also helps attach to the extension after it is launched.